# how i can select multiple values from check box?

Tags: php, html, forms

hi i have multiple option in check box and when visitor or customer select multiple option then how i can get multiple values?  plz explain with code thanks

Comment: Why not simply try out and do a `print_r($_POST);` in the receiving script?

Answer (score 2):

Name the checkboxes with `[]` (or PHP will drop all but one of them (I don't recall if it is the first or last)).

```
<input type=checkbox name="foo[]" value="some value">
```

Then they will be accessible as an array in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` superglobal.

```
$_GET['foo'][]
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, set all the name tags to be the same for all your checkboxes (with `[]`). Then in your script, the values will be available as an array

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="4" />
```

PHP:

```
print_r($_REQUEST['tags']);
```

Reference: http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/php-checkbox-array-in-form-handling-multiple-checkbox-values-in-an-array.html

Comment: can we do this without array ?

Comment: You can parse the raw data, but that way lies wheel reinvention, pain and mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="baz" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="qux" />

<?php
    print_r($_POST['foo']);
```